# AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'pyplot'

Tags: matplotlib, anaconda

I am running Anaconda 4.2.9 and Python 3.5.2 on MacOS 10.12.  Whenever I try the simple command

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

I get the following error message

```
 [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-eff513f636fd> in <module>()
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

/Users/ghoetker/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in <module>()
      8 import matplotlib
      9
---> 10 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     11 import matplotlib.animation as manimation
     12

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'pyplot'
```

I get this error whether I use iPython, a Jupyter Notebook, PyCharm, Spyder or Rodeo. I've used conda to uninstall and reinstall matplotlib to no avail. The really odd thing is that it worked once this morning, but hasn't since.  I'm not aware of anything I changed in the interim. I've found that if I downgrade to matplotlib 1.5.1, it works just fine. However, that requires some more meaningful downgrades, like going from Spyder 3 to Spyder 2. So, I'd really like to figure out how to use the current version of matplotlib.

I would really appreciate any recommendations or pointers anyone can provide.  Obviously, I'm happy to provide any additional information that would help with debugging.

Comment: What is odd, is that it raises an `Attribute Error` here instead of an `Import Error`. Is this error only happening with pyplot or other submodules as well? What happens if you type `import pylab`? Is the same error raised?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  `import pylab` gives the same error `AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'pyplot'`.

I was able to import `matplotlib.dates`, `matplotlib.animation` and `matplotlib.colors` with no error.

I confirmed that `pyplot,.py` is actually present in the appropriate directory.

Very confused and appreciating any help!!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following sequence of commands and it worked for me:

```
conda uninstall pyzmq
conda install pyzmq
conda install jupyter
```